# iOS - Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSProgress'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to download a file using Alamofire, with progress. But I get this error at the `progress` line.

`Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSProgress'`

What's the problem? All the examples I've seen, namely [the official one](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-a-file-wprogress), do the exact same thing!

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, nsurl!.absoluteString,     destination: { (temporaryURL, response) in
    return filepath
})
    .progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in // <------ ERROR HERE
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.progressBar?.progress = totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead
        })
    }
    .response { (request, response, _, error) in
        self.loadImageFromFile(filepath.absoluteString)
}
```

[image]

## EDIT:

After @mvoelkl's suggestion, I added parenthesis to the progress function. But the result stayed the same:
[image]

Comment: I'm still looking for answer to this as well!

Comment: @FarisSbahi Just use NSURLSession, it as easy as Alamofire for downloading files.

Comment: Fair enough. I think it's about time I make the switch back to native-only. 3rd party libraries will never see the support to keep up with constant Xcode and Swift development so long as they remain as underfunded as they are right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this issue fix when update your `Alamofire pod` .

Here mention this issue :- https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON/issues/40

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's one of the first things that I tried :-( I updated the pods, cleaned and rebuilt the whole project, but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm using `Alamofire', '~> 3.0'` is working perfectly.

Comment: Just try for testing `Alamofire', '~> 3.0'` its working.

Comment: I couldn't downgrade the pod! Should I delete the files and then run `pod install`?

Comment: Nope! Even removing the Alamofire pod completely and then installing it didn't work.

Comment: I haven't set any break points. Anyways, thanks again for the help. But I deleted the code, I'm using NSURLSession now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117082/discussion-between-mitul-marsonia-and-mnvoh).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, nsurl!.absoluteString, destination: { (temporaryURL, response) in
    return file path
})
    .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
        let status = Float(totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.progressBar?.progress = status
        })
    }
    .response { (request, response, _, error) in
        self.loadImageFromFile(filepath.absoluteString)
}
```

What may **not** work in the above is *totalBytesExpectedToRead*. It sometimes returns -1, so you may need plug the size of the file you are downloading without resorting to Alamofire.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to add Float around progress.fractionCompleted, so use it like this:

```
.uploadProgress{ progress in
    self.updateProgressBar(imagesToDo: images.count, prog: Float(progress.fractionCompleted))
}
```

thanks to:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1652#issuecomment-259020449

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, fixed by using the following code:

```
Alamofire.upload(.PUT, url, file: file)
    .progress({ (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
        print("test")
    })
```

Mind the added parentheses for .progress(), found it by generating the code stub with Xcode. Seems there's a mistake in the documentation, if you can confirm this we should file an issue on GitHub ;)

Comment: `.response` has the same exact syntax, without parenthesis and it works. I don't think that's the problem. I think some other variable is masking the progress function in my *version* of Alamofire. i.e., there's a variable with the same exact name.

Comment: Well, if I'm correct, i think your solution could make sense. Adding the parenthesis could make the call explicit that we want a method, not a variable. I'm not an swift expert, but that could be it.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Check my "Edit". Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: Seems you're calling the property _progress_ (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Request.swift#L51) and not the method _progress(closure: ((Int64, Int64, Int64) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self_ (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Request.swift#L141). Tried a Clean and Build?

Comment: Oh, I've tried that a thousand times. And honestly I have no idea what am I doing wrong that causes a property call instead of a function call, other than that there's a bug in this version of alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

This issue plagued me too. It was caused by an ambiguous issue with NSURLRequest.progress and Alamofire.Request.progress.

To fix the issue I modified Alamofire's source.

Open Alamofire/Request.swift (v3.4.x)

On line 141, rename the function to something that is not progress, I chose requestProgress.

From:

```
public func progress(closure: ((Int64, Int64, Int64) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
```

To:

```
public func requestProgress(closure: ((Int64, Int64, Int64) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
```

Proceed to use the function as before with no compiler issues.

Comment: I think it's much preferable if someone made that change to the repo using a pull request. I would advise against making that change in your local version of alamofire.