# Alamofire 4 multipart request upload progress

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How should I track progress of my multipart upload request using Alamofire 4?

My encodingCompletion handler:

```
encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let uploadRequest, _, _):
            uploadRequest.uploadProgress {
                p in
                print(p.completedUnitCount, p.totalUnitCount)
            }
            break
        case .failure( _):
            print("Failed to encode upload")
        }
}
```

The error I get says:

> Cannot call value of not-function type 'Progress'

Comment: Have a look at a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326889/ios-cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-nsprogress

Comment: have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631823/swift-3-alamofilre-4-0-multipart-upload-with-progress/39633314#39633314

Comment: @EktaMakadiya I did that, it's right in the code I posted.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(URL(string: "http://example.com/url1")!, withName: "one")
            multipartFormData.append(URL(string: "http://example.com/url2")!, withName: "two")
        },
        to: "http://example.com/to",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
                upload.uploadProgress { progress in

                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: I've posted my full implementation of the multipart upload now. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `fractionCompleted`, `totalUnitCount` and `completedUnitCount` with a cast to Int or Float (depending on what you need).

It works!

source: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1652#issuecomment-259020449